# Merge and compare

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a logic to merge all the Batches from `message2` variable. It will merge all the Batch if there is a duplicate Batch name (AA, BB) and calculate the lines.

```
var message2 = {
    Batches: [ 
        {Batch: "AA", Lines: 1 },
        {Batch: "BB", Lines: 2 },
        {Batch: "BB", Lines: 6 }
    ]
}
```

Become:

```
[ { Batch: 'AA', Lines: 1 }, { Batch: 'BB', Lines: 8 } ]
```

This is done by `reduce()` method.

In the `forEach` loop, it loops all the `mergedBatches` (after merged) and compares with the batch in the `Worker` variable. It will need to find the same batch name if the `Worker` line is more then `mergedBatches` line then set `mergedBatches` to match the `Worker` line.

```
var message2 = {
    Batches: [ 
        {Batch: "AA", Lines: 1 },
        {Batch: "BB", Lines: 2 },
        {Batch: "BB", Lines: 6 }
    ]
}

var Worker = { 
    Batches: [
        {Batch: "AA", Lines: 2 },
        {Batch: "BB", Lines: 3 },
    ]
}

var mergedBatches = message2.Batches.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
    var existObj = acc.find(b => b.Batch === obj.Batch);

    if(existObj) {
      existObj.Lines += obj.Lines;
      return acc;
    }

    acc.push({Batch: obj.Batch, Lines: obj.Lines});
    return acc;
},[]);

mergedBatches.forEach((b) => {
    var workerBatch = Worker.Batches.find(wB => wB.Batch === b.Batch);
    if (b.Lines >= workerBatch.Lines) {
        b.Lines = workerBatch.Lines;
    }
});


console.log(mergedBatches)
```

Final result which is working as expected:

```
[ { Batch: 'AA', Lines: 1 }, { Batch: 'BB', Lines: 3 } ]
```

Is there a way to refactor this code to make it readable or a better way?

Comment: This is pretty simple with a library like underscore/lodash. Are you using one of those?

Comment: @tokland I don't want to use any library.

Comment: Isn't possible to optimize at creation; to use a map and just to add lines if the key already exists in the obj? (is it you who handles the creation?) This way you would not need to use the reduce part

Comment: How big will your data set get because this will affect the pattern you should use.

Comment: @EmettSpeer No more than 20  data set  (objects in array)

Comment: I'm not sure that with a small data set like this you can get much faster then what you're currently doing. There is also the issue that any further possible performance gains will likely result in messier code.

Comment: @EmettSpeer It is not about performance issue I am concern about. Mainly is there a way to refactor this code (cleaner way) rather than performance gains.

Comment: > `if (workerBatch.Lines > b.Lines)` - this is a desired condition, right?

Comment: @amankkg Yes. `[ { Batch: 'AA', Lines: 1 }, { Batch: 'BB', Lines: 8 } ]` and after desired condition become: `[ { Batch: 'AA', Lines: 1 }, { Batch: 'BB', Lines: 3 } ]`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I mean that in the description you said the opposite - `if the Worker line is more then mergedBatches line then set mergedBatches to match the Worker line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter version:

1. if `mergedBatches` should not contain references to `message2.Batches` entries you can use destructuring: `acc.push({ ...cur })`;
2. one-line `if/else` should be more readable without the brackets;
3. null-check in the latest condition: `find` can return undefined.

---

```js
const message2 = {
  Batches: [ 
    {Batch: "AA", Lines: 1 },
    {Batch: "BB", Lines: 2 },
    {Batch: "BB", Lines: 6 }
  ]
}

const Worker = { 
  Batches: [
    {Batch: "AA", Lines: 2 },
    {Batch: "BB", Lines: 3 },
  ]
}

const mergedBatches = message2.Batches.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const prev = acc.find(x => x.Batch === cur.Batch)

  if (prev) prev.Lines += cur.Lines
  else acc.push(cur)

  return acc
}, [])

mergedBatches.forEach((mb) => {
  const wb = Worker.Batches.find(x => x.Batch === mb.Batch)

  if (wb && wb.Lines < mb.Lines ) mb.Lines = wb.Lines
})

console.log(mergedBatches)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more straight forward and should be faster:

```
const mergeBatches = (message) => {
  const obj = {};

  for (let i = message.Batches.length; i--;) {
    const current = message.Batches[i];

    if (current.Batch in obj) {
      obj[current.Batch] += current.Lines;
    } else {
      obj[current.Batch] = current.Lines;
    }
  }

  const arr = [];

  for (let key in obj) {
    arr.push({
      Batch: key,
      Lines: obj[key]
    })
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Its really good that you're learning functional patterns, but they aren't always the fastest.

For example, your code you have `acc.find`. Underneath the hood, `find` is iterating over the array `acc` every time that function executes which makes the complexity O(n * n) *I think its this, someone comment if I'm wrong*.

In the function I provided, you're only iterating over the Batches array once which makes this O(n).

Comment: Thank you. The logic is missing to check the number of Lines between `mergeBatches` and `Worker ` variables.  See `if (b.Lines >= workerBatch.Lines) { }` from my topic.

Comment: The question will come down to how big is the data set. In this case its possible that the original will run faster then your updated code even with it using `find` so its hard to say.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Wouldn't be more than 20 objects in the array.

Comment: With the current data set there is not really a nice clean way to deal with it. Though I'm thinking through the problem set.

Answer (score 0):

From your current structure this would be another way to arrive to your expecting result:

```
const merged = {};
message2.Batches.forEach(b => {
  if(merged[b.Batch]) {
    merged[b.Batch].Lines += b.Lines;
  } else {
    merged[b.Batch] = b;
  }
});

const result = [];
Worker.Batches.forEach(b => {
  if (merged[b.Batch] && merged[b.Batch].Lines > b.Lines) {
    merged[b.Batch].Lines = b.Lines;
  }
  result.push(merged[b.Batch]);
});

// Output
[{ "Batch": "AA", "Lines": 1 }, { "Batch": "BB", "Lines": 3 }]
```